# Custom post query breaks original search term in Wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress, loops

I want to create a loop and query posts by their author role and display the results of a search term based on the authors role.

When I apply my query the posts returned are for the user role and not the original search term.

Here's my query and the loop;

```
    $ids = get_users(
        array(
            'role'   => 'administrator' ,
            'fields' => 'ID'
            )
    );


    $query = new WP_Query( 
        array( 
            'author__in' => $ids,
        )
    );


        // If the query has data
        if($query->have_posts() ) :

                // Post loop
                while ($query->have_posts() ) : 

                    // Setup post data
                    $query->the_post();
                    ?>

                    <!-- Do HTML markup and template tags here, eg. the_content(), the_title() etc.. -->
                    <h1>You're a post from administrator - <?php the_title(); ?></h1>


                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search' ); ?>

                    <?php
                endwhile;

        // End "If the query has data"
        endif;
```

This is on my search.php page ...

So for example if I have two posts published from the user type 'administrator' one of those posts is tagged with 'England' and the other is not - so when I go to the search form and enter 'England' I would expect this code to display the one post out of those two however it doesn't, it displays both.

So it appears to be just displaying all posts from the user type 'administrator' and ignoring the search term.

I've got no idea why that is the case, in my mind this code should be working so if anyone has any advice or can point me in the right direction that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a custom loop so you need to add the search term back into the query args.

```
 $query = new WP_Query( 
        array( 
            'author__in' => $ids,
            's' => $_GET['s']
        )
    );
```

Comment: You Sir are a beautiful thing.

Plugs straight it - whole thing works like a treat, thank you!